# Get last index rebuild date in sybase

Tags: sybase, indexing

Does anyone know of a way to query the date a sybase index was last rebuild?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the only way, the create date of the index:

```
select name, id, crdate from sysindexes where id = object_id('TableName')
```

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "rebuild".  That provides the date of the last CREATE INDEX, not the date of the last REORG REBUILD.